# Entity Framework - Get row count of a (group by Subquery)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have this simple expression to get each Order's amount:

```
public IQueryable<Orders> GetAccountSummery()
{
    return context.Orders.GroupBy(a => new { orderNo = a.orderNo })
   .Select(b => new 
   { 
   orderNo = b.Key.orderNo,
   amount = b.Sum(r => r.amount)
   });
}
```

I needed to Get The total number of records returned by the previous expression:

**SQL**

```
select COUNT(1)  from 
(
 SELECT orderNo,SUM(amount) Amount  
FROM  Orders
group by orderNo
)tbl -- I get 125,000 row count here
```

**EF**

```
public int GetOrdersCount()
{
    return GetAccountSummery().Count(); // This guy here gives 198,000 rows which counts all rows from orders table
   // The following line gives the correct row count:
    return GetAccountSummery().AsEnumerable().Count(); // 125,000 row
}
```

The problem with `GetAccountSummery().AsEnumerable().Count()` is that it **runs the query first at the server side** then **calculates the correct row count at client side** (consider the table size here)

Is there any way to get only the correct count without executing the select statement ?

**EDIT**

If that is not possible with `groupBy` subquery, why is it for `Where` subs?

Answer (score 0):

The way you currently have it structured? No. You'll always execute the `.Select()`statement because `.Count()` employs immediate execution (see [here for a list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882641.aspx)). However, `.Count()` also has an override which takes in a `Func`, which you should be able to use to grab the count without having to perform the select first, as so:

```
context.Orders.GroupBy(a => new { orderNo = a.orderNo })
              .Count(a => a.Key.orderNo != string.Empty);
```

EDIT: Whoops, forgot that it was a bool. Edited accordingly.

EDIT 2: Per the comments, I don't think it is possible, since you'll always need to have that select in there at any given time, and `.Count()` will always call it. Sorry.

Comment: I get this message on the count func: cannot implicitly convert type int to bool, which means count parameter should be bool

Comment: Since `orderNo` is `int` I tried `Count(a => a.Key.orderNo != 0)` I get the same incorrect result 198,000..

Comment: Oddly enough, the following SQL is executed :`SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE 0 <> [Extent1].[orderNo]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]` Which still not grouping by orderNo

Comment: That's fine. Thanks bro for helping